# What is the proper way to enter a MYSQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

I read the docs and it seems in order to have a stored procedure I must enter some commands as follow:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE
myDB.RoutingName                        /* Routine name */
(IN parameter_1_id INTEGER)                 /* Parameter list */

BEGIN                                           /* Routine body */
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = parameter_1_id 
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

I tried to enter above lines into a file and then copy/paste them into phpmyadmin SQL section to feed it into MYSQL server, but I receives syntax error.

I am wondering what is the proper way to enter stored procedures? Specially when they are large and consist of many many lines ?

Comment: If you want a good, general guide for creating stored procs, go into MySQL Administrator, click on backup and create a backup with backup type as "SQL Files". This will give you a very nice template that you can copy from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a ; after the query and the delimiter after END should be the one you specified first.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE
myDB.RoutingName                        /* Routine name */
(IN parameter_1_id INTEGER)                 /* Parameter list */

BEGIN                                           /* Routine body */
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = parameter_1_id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I actually found the answer.

The BEST way to enter stored procedure is to save it into a file like:

myprocedure.sql

Then save the SQL statement like :

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE
myDB.RoutingName                            /* Routine name */
(IN parameter_1_id INTEGER)                 /* Parameter list */

BEGIN                                             /* Routine body */
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = parameter_1_id;  /* first statement */ 
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id = parameter_1_id;  /* second statement */
       /* Loops and other statement go here, each separated by a ; */
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then go to command line and issue:

```
$ mysql -u username -p < myprocedure.sql
```

Enter your password and now your procedure is saved.
From now on you can call that procedure by issuing CALL command in MYSQL client shell prompt.